# Typescript definition file intersection type function signature

Tags: typescript

i am stumbled across a typescript definition file with some intersection type function signatures. They are from `@types/cropppie`  in the file `index.d.ts`:

```
result(options: ResultOptions & { type: 'base64' }): Promise<string>;
result(options: ResultOptions & { type: 'html' }): Promise<HTMLElement>;
result(options: ResultOptions & { type: 'blob' }): Promise<Blob>;
result(options: ResultOptions & { type: 'canvas' }): Promise<HTMLCanvasElement>;
result(options?: ResultOptions): Promise<HTMLCanvasElement>;
```

I am not able to invoke the function `result` with `type: 'base64'`, so the typescript compiler correctly identifies the return value as `Promise<string>`.

When invoked like

```
const opts = new ResultOptions(...);
result({...opts, ...{type: 'base64'}}).then(data => ...);
```

the typescript compiler identifies `data` as a `HTMLCanvasElement`, but is indeed a base64 encoded string.

Can someone point out how to correctly pass the arguments, so the typescript compiler will identify `data` as a string?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that the problem is connected to the way params passed into the result function are prepared. I've changed a bit this preparation and it looks like the code you mentioned started working. Instead of:

```
{...opts, ...{type: 'base64'}}
```

I wrote:

```
{ ...opts, type: 'base64' }
```

You can check my example on the [Playground site](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20ResultOptions%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20param1%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20ClassA%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20result(options%3A%20ResultOptions%20%26%20%7B%20type%3A%20'base64'%20%7D)%3A%20Promise%3Cstring%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20result(options%3A%20ResultOptions%20%26%20%7B%20type%3A%20'html'%20%7D)%3A%20Promise%3CHTMLElement%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20result(options%3A%20ResultOptions%20%26%20%7B%20type%3A%20'blob'%20%7D)%3A%20Promise%3CBlob%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20result(options%3A%20ResultOptions%20%26%20%7B%20type%3A%20'canvas'%20%7D)%3A%20Promise%3CHTMLCanvasElement%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20result(options%3F%3A%20ResultOptions)%3A%20Promise%3CHTMLCanvasElement%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20result(options%3F%3A%20ResultOptions)%3A%20Promise%3Cany%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20((options%20as%20any).type%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22base64%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Promise%3Cstring%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(resolve)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%22some%20string%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Promise%3Cany%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(resolve)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%7B%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20opts%20%3D%20new%20ResultOptions()%3B%0D%0Aconst%20instanceA%20%3D%20new%20ClassA()%3B%0D%0AinstanceA.result(%7B%20...opts%2C%20type%3A%20'base64'%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.then(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(data%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(%22data(string)%3A%20%22%20%2B%20data)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0AinstanceA.result(opts)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.then(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(data%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(%22data(any)%3A%20%22%20%2B%20data)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B).

Here is a full code of the example:

```
class ResultOptions {
    param1: any;
}

class ClassA {
    result(options: ResultOptions & { type: 'base64' }): Promise<string>;
    result(options: ResultOptions & { type: 'html' }): Promise<HTMLElement>;
    result(options: ResultOptions & { type: 'blob' }): Promise<Blob>;
    result(options: ResultOptions & { type: 'canvas' }): Promise<HTMLCanvasElement>;
    result(options?: ResultOptions): Promise<HTMLCanvasElement>;
    result(options?: ResultOptions): Promise<any> {
        if ((options as any).type === "base64") {
            return new Promise<string>(
                (resolve) => {
                    resolve("some string");
                }
            );

        } else {
            return new Promise<any>(
                (resolve) => {
                    resolve({});
                }
            );
        }
    }
}

const opts = new ResultOptions();
const instanceA = new ClassA();
instanceA.result({ ...opts, type: 'base64' })
    .then(
        (data: string) => {
            alert("data(string): " + data);
        }
    );

instanceA.result(opts)
    .then(
        (data: any) => {
            alert("data(any): " + data);
        }
    );
```

Comment: Oh simple as that. Indeed, when i am not using another inner object, the compiler recognizes it correctly. Many thanks for your really great answer, beautiful work!